# Error when deleting MindsDB model from MongoDB

Tags: python, machine-learning, mindsdb

I have a MindsDB model named `hrd` and I intended to delete the model by running the below command as per the documentation.

```
db.models.deleteOne({name: "hrd"})
```

While  running the command and I got hit with the below error.

```
MongoServerError 'unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

How can I delete specific models from a MongoDB database integration in MindsDB?

Comment: We are resolving this. You can check the status here https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/pull/4346. Should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Resolved https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/pull/4346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This open issue is being resolved by the MindsDB engineering team, and will be fixed in the next release (24-48hrs).

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/issues/4345) on their Github page. Right now deleting the model in MongoDB Compass works.